# Assigning part of the returned json data to an array in TypeScript and Angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am currently retrieving json data from a file with various fields - i am interested in 2 fields and each of the 2 field i would like to have them set to different arrays.

SERVICE file:

```
getCourseType(){
    return this._http.get('url')
     .map((res:Response) => <ICourseType[]> res.json())
     .do(data =>console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

COMPONENTS.ts file:

```
courseType: ICourseType[];
courseName: any[] = [];
courseRoster: any[] = [];

getCourseType(){ //function called from ngOnInit()
    this.dataService.getCourseType().subscribe(
      data => this.courseType = data,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "courseTitle": "English",
    "courseNumber": 340B,
    "roster": 23,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "courseTitle": "AP History",
    "courseNumber": 1420,
    "roster": 14
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "courseTitle": "Art",
    "courseNumber": 42A,
    "roster": 30
  }
]
```

Currently i am return the json object but if i am interested in gathering all the `courseTitle` of each of the courses into one array and then all the `roster` number of each of the courses into one array - where should i do that? In the service or in my components?

Comment: Why was the question voted down without a comment or explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component file

```
courseType: ICourseType[];
courseName: any[];
courseRoster: any[];

getCourseType(){ //function called from ngOnInit()
    this.dataService.getCourseType().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.courseType = data
        this.courseType.forEach(course=>{
             this.courseName.push(course.courseTitle);
             this.courseRoster.push(course.roster);
          })  
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

Comment: I just tried this but in my console i am getting an error stating : `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` and referring to `this.courseName` and `this.courseRoster` as undefined.

Comment: it was resolved by setting `courseName: any[] = []; courseRoster: any[] =[]`

Comment: @bluePearl stop using `any`